# Same Query Gives Different Output In MSSQL And Hibernate 3

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

**Users**

- Userid
- userName
- password
- status

**Issue**

- IssueNum
- issueDescription
- status
- creationdate

**IssueAssigned**

- issueNumber
- issueAssignedTo
- issueAssignedBy
- comments

In my primefaces datatable I am fetching these value using following query

```
SELECT I.issue_number, I.issue_describtion, U.first_name,US.first_name 
FROM ISSUES I
LEFT JOIN  ISSUE_ASSIGNED IA
ON  I.issue_number = IA.Issue_number
LEFT JOIN USERS U
ON U.id = IA.assigned_to_user_id
LEFT JOIN USERS US
ON   US.id = IA.assigned_by_user_id
```

The Admin who is also a user assigns issue to another user

In MSSQL this above query works fine gives me proper record for U.firstName and US.FirstName as they are different user.

query in MSSQL returns

```
PER-1675        Perform - Evaluation Form Export does not pull any data in Legacy Export Tool (Due 8/14)    Ameh    Sandip
PER-2048        Calculation of scores fails when the lower/upper bound value of a calculation text result is a  Ameh    Sandip
```

But in Hibernate for the same query both firstName and US.firstName gives same result

code

```
@Override
    public List<Object> getIssueListForAssigingIssue (){
        List<Object> allIssueList = getHibernateTemplate()
                .getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT I.issue_number, I.issue_describtion, IT.issue_type,U.first_name ,US.first_name "
                        + "FROM ISSUES I "
                        + "LEFT JOIN  ISSUE_ASSIGNED IA "
                        + "ON  I.issue_number = IA.Issue_number "
                        + "LEFT JOIN USERS U "
                        + "ON U.id = IA.assigned_to_user_id "
                        + "LEFT JOIN USERS US "
                        + "ON  US.id = IA.assigned_by_user_id ").list();
            return allIssueList;
    }
```

query in hibernate returns

```
PER-1675        Perform - Evaluation Form Export does not pull any data in Legacy Export Tool (Due 8/14)    Ameh    Ameh
PER-2048        Calculation of scores fails when the lower/upper bound value of a calculation text result is a  Ameh    Ameh
```

Comment: Are those the only two rows that are returned?  The result sets might be the same but in different orders.

Comment: that was just an example actually there is only one admin who assigns issues.

Comment: The Hibernate query uses JOIN. The direct SQL uses LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @gbn I tried both the ways no luck!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by giving alias to both the column somehow hibernate gets confused between the two columns